# Diode the wrong way

Tags: multimeter

What will happen to the current if a diode is placed the wrong way round?

Should the current be 0?

I need to measure the current when the diode is the wrong way round.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Take a couple of minutes to look up the function and operation of a diode, there are a few graphs that will be informative to you!

Comment: Take care that the battery voltage does not exceed diode reverse breakdown voltage. Easy enough with a 1N4148, not so easy with a LED. Some of the latter will take only a few volts.

Comment: @Ben: What is the *wrong* way? Sometime your wrong way is the right way (photodiodes, zener diodes). I think what you mean is commonly called *reverse*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this really _"Doesn't show any research effort"_ in my view.

Comment: If you need to measure it, won't that answer your questions?

Comment: I have measured it. It comes out 53.291uA. But when i place a different diode the current is 0. And from what i've read and watched on YouTube it should be 0. Because it is a open circuit. This is why i am getting confused.

Comment: Exactly what kind of diode are you using?

Comment: @ben it'll never be zero current because all diodes have a reverse leakage current - if your measurement device doesn't show fractions of a micro amp then it may indicate zero when there is actually 100 nA flowing. For instance the 1N4148 has 25 nA maximum reverse current with 20 volts applied that can rise to 5o uA at 150 degC.

Answer (score 11):

Diodes have a small leakage current when reverse biased and that is the current you will measure - leakage current: -

[image]

Comment: I have looked it up. And when a diode is reversed the current is 0.  Because it breaks the circuit.

Comment: Does 53.291uA sound like a leakage current?

Comment: @Ben That sounds very much like a leakage current.

Comment: 50 uA seems like a very large leakage current to me, at least for a standard signal or low-power rectifier. For a Schottky it would not be surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there will be reverse leakage when a diode is reverse biased. Due to the increased potential, holes on the n side of semiconductor are dragged to negative terminal of the battery and electrons on the p side is dragged to the positive terminal of the battery. This constitute a reverse a current which is a also called as reverse saturation current. 
This is because even though increase in reverse potential, current will not be increased that much for a certain limit. This leakage current varies with diodes according to the spec sheet.